# Meaning of "drive" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

A newspaper headline:

> Bengal **drives** Modi comeback: Polls

[[[Bengal: one of India's states.

Modi: India's present PM.

And voting just concluded yesterday.]]]

All meanings in **Cambridge** and other online dictionaries didn't help me to understand.

What's the meaning of **drive** in this context?

Please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The title means that Modi is making a comeback in the polls and it's because of Bengal.

The relevant definition in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drive) is:

> Cause (something abstract) to happen or develop.
>   *‘the consumer has been driving the economy for a number of years’*